# Is anyone else seeing massive deindexes over Memorial Day weekend 2019?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, bing-webmaster-tools

Is anyone else seeing massive deindexes over Memorial Day weekend 2019?

When I'm doing a site search it's saying that I have 4,500 pages indexed in Google, though on Google Search Console says 14,550. The traffic from Google is low and I'm inclined to believe the live results over Google Search Console.

No security issues or manual actions are reported on Google Search Console. Bing Webmaster Tools also shows a stark drop in indexation.

On Friday I set each of the sitemaps to be re-crawled because of an issue where our meta descriptions were swapped out for product descriptions. I read [this](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/new-google-indexing-issue/309479/) on Search Engine Land and figured that it might be the cause. I wanted to ask around to see if anyone else noticed a drop.

Comment: I edited this with the assumption that you meant _Memorial Day_ (this weekend) and not Labor Day weekend last September.

Comment: This may not be related, but in the last month Google has been having trouble maintaining the index: [April 2019 Google Outages Due to Human Error - Search Engine Journal](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/april-2019-google-outages-human-error/309755/)

Comment: Yea, I knew of that. We're still going down, but with no good reason. The scary part is that search console claims we are gaining pages, but live search says we are losing them.